# Android SQL query() doesnt replace question mark

Tags: android, sqlite

Somehow the questions mark in the query are not replaced and I can not figure out why.
I always get the Query (looked into while debugging):

> SELECT message, timestamp
>
> FROM chatMessage
>
> WHERE chatId = ?
>
> ORDER BY timestamp ASC
>
> LIMIT 5

in the code below:

```
public ArrayList<String> queryLastMessages(String chatId, int count){
  SQLiteDatabase db = new DatabaseHelper(context).getReadableDatabase();
  
  String[] columns = {
            COLUMN_NAME_CHAT_MESSAGE,
            COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP
    };
    
  String selection =  COLUMN_NAME_CHAT_ID + " = ?";
    
  String[] selectionArgs = {
            chatId
    };
    
  // ToDo: Ascending or Descending?
  Cursor cursor = db.query(
          TABLE_CHAT_MESSAGE,
          columns,
          selection,
          selectionArgs,
          null,
          null,
          COLUMN_NAME_TIMESTAMP + " ASC",
          String.valueOf(count));

  cursor.moveToFirst();
    
  ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  if(cursor.getCount() != 0){
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
      arrayList.add(cursor.getString(0));
      cursor.moveToNext();
    }
  }

  return arrayList;
}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong? Thanks for your help.

Ray

Comment: *somehow the questions mark in the query are not replaced* ??? it will never be replaced ... thats how parameters binding works ...

Comment: Does the query *work*?

Comment: @Selvin:
Thanks for your hint. Because of that, i found the real problem :D
=> Parameter chatId was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(query);
stmt.bindString(1, stringYouWantToReplaceQuestionMark);
stmt.execute();
```